# Using Inotify and/or epoll to monitor processes terminating, perhaps using the /proc/<PID> directory

Tags: linux, temporary-files

Have an issue where we want to be able to receive an event in one process if another, unrelated process terminates. The first process is sent the PID of the second process. The first process allocates resources based related to the second process. If the second process terminates normally, it notifies the first process before exiting. If it crashes, the first process needs to be notified. Initially tried using `epoll()` on files in the `/proc/<PID>` directory. `epoll()` can't open the directory. Then tried `Inotify()` but that apparently only works with user process defined files and directories.
Then thought about having the second process create a temporary file and have it delete on process termination, but a crash (or kill -9) does not clean up the temporary file.
I'm aware of waiting for child processes, but this is not a parent-child process relationship.
There has to be some means to be able to do this.
Want this to be event driven, not periodically checking the `/proc` directory for the presence of the `/proc/<PID>` subdir.

Have tried `NamedTemporaryFile()` in Python, but the file persists after the process terminates.
Have tried `epoll()` on a file in the `/proc/<PID>` directory, ones that `epoll()` doesn't return an error on. The ones that can be opened generate lots of events even with just the `EPOLLHUP` and `EPOLLRDHUP` flags.  Probably `epoll()` isn't the right API.
Have not tried `Inotify` yet, but that is not supposed to monitor system files and directories.
Ideas?

Comment: Apparently, can't use Inotify() on the /proc directory. So that's out. This needs to be a wait on an event, not a poll.  Do not want to waste CPU cycles in a polling loop.

Comment: Recent kernels have [`pidfd_open(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_open.2.html) which creates descriptors that poll as readable when the process exits. Sounds perfect if you can use it.

Comment: When you say that a process sends its pid to the other, what are you using to communicate ?